# Is it possible to hydrate (or something else) single component?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

My case: I have a page preloader, but it makes using react and it's to long (first paint). SSR could solve this problem, but it's too difficult (I mean solving this problem by full SSR).

I want to use something like React.hydrate but for one single component.
I have `<MyCustomPreloader />` component which renders `<div class="loader" />`, but it render with a long delay (after loading the page).

My idea: For example, inside `index.html` I can make `<div class="loader" />` which will be visible at first paint. Main problem say `<MyCustomPreloader />` that I have **already rendered** `div` and he must use it without creating new.

I could find the necessary DOM inside the component and work with it, but this means abandoning React and continue to work directly with the DOM component.

I tried to manually add `<div class="loader" />` into `<div id="root"></div>` and use `React.hydrate` instead of `React.render` and **it works!** But `React.hydrate` tries to hydrate every components before and after loader and this solution is kludge.

I believe that there is a function that can partially hydrate a single component (say to component "use this DOM" instead of making same new element), but I cannot find it.

**For example:**

```
const loader = ReactDOM.someMagicFunction(<MyCustomPreloader />, document.getElementById("loader"))
```

Example of this kludge: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-meadow-qgz6j Description: I have "pre-rendered" loader in `index.html`, and react after loooong loading gets it and USED it (this DOM element).

Can I hydrate single component with some DOM element?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq, I think you overcomplicated things, everyone using loaders in React and first paint wasn't a problem for that. Show us a minimal example with the "slow" loader painting

Comment: Because your question is so general, you can use `React.createPortal` as a general answer

Comment: @DennisVash createPortal will say to component "you have to render HERE", and he will render NEW dom elements, without rehydrating it

Comment: @DennisVash Example of this kludge: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-meadow-qgz6j Description: I have "pre-rendered" loader in `index.html`, and react after loooong loading gets it and USED it (this DOM element).

Comment: How long? I don't see any performance issues here.

Comment: @DennisVash ... this is a example. Real project css+js ~10mb and user with 3G will wait ~10 sec before all JS+CSS will be loaded and React creates "loader"

Comment: You can simply put a loader in html and when everything is loaded, you just remove the laoder and run render.